# About Python syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

```
def get_input():

    '''
    Continually prompt the user for a number, 1,2 or 3 until
    the user provides a good input. You will need a type conversion.
    :return: The users chosen number as an integer
    '''
    #pass # REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR CODE

    n = input ("Enter the number 1,2 and 3? ")

    while n > 0 and n < 4:
        print("Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3")
        n = input ("Enter the number 1,2 or 3? ")
    return (n)


get_input()
```

I am not getting the answer and it's just not working, I am looking for answer like this,

```
Give me one of 1,2 or 3: sid
Invalid input!
Give me one of 1,2 or 3: 34
Invalid input!
Give me one of 1,2 or 3: -7
Invalid input!
Give me one of 1,2 or 3: 0
Invalid input!
Give me one of 1,2 or 3: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your code would have spit out an error `TypeError: unorderable types...`, when you ask a question include the error and the traceback, *it's just not working* is usually not very informative,  even if you cast your code will crash if a user enters a string that cannot be cast to an int, you should use a try/except

Answer (score 3):

The [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) built-in function returns a value of type `str`.

As is specified in the (doc)string right after the declaration of function `get_input()`:

> You will need a type conversion.

So, you must wrap it in an `int()` to convert it to an integer `int`.

```
n = int(input("Enter the number 1,2 or 3? "))
```

Then you can use comparison operators to evaluate if it is `in` the qualified range of accepted values :

```
   # Your comparisons are mixed.
   # You can use the in operator which is intuitive and expressive
   while n not in [1, 2, 3]:
        print("Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3")

        # remember to wrap it in an int() call again
        n = int(input ("Enter the number 1,2 or 3? "))
    return (n)
```

If you supply numbers this works perfectly:

```
Enter the number 1,2 and 3? 10
Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3
Enter the number 1,2 and 3? -1
Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3
Enter the number 1,2 and 3? 15
Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3
Enter the number 1,2 and 3? 104
Invalid Input, give the  number between 1 to 3
```

But if you supply a single character or a string (type `str`), you'll get an error:

```
Enter the number 1,2 and 3? a

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

This is beyond the scope of the question but you might [want to look into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742432/python-error-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-stop).

Anyway, your while condition is setting me off..

---

It seems that you might be using `Python 2` with the `print_function` imported through `__future__`. (or else the comparison between different types would raise a `TypeError` in the `while` statement).

Check your version of python `python -V` [in the command line] and:

If using python 2 instead of `input()` use `raw_input()`:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter the number 1, 2, 3: ")
```

If I am wrong and you are indeed using `Python 3.x`, use `int(input())` as explained.

Comment: its Python 3.3, and thanks man. Let me check if it works,

Comment: Ah, not really sure about the behavior of these in `3.3`. You should probably get the newest version so you don't get all confused.

Comment: its working fine, except the fact that it does not work for,,                                                   Give me one of 1,2 or 3: sid
Invalid input!

Comment: Yup, you need to perform some [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=exception) for cases where you enter a string.