# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in Python 3 and need some help, my error is:

```
"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''  "
```

any ideas? The code I'm using is the following:

```
liste = [1, 2, 3]

def liste_pop():
    print(liste)
    pop = int(input('remove = Enter um das letzte Element der Liste auszugeben + entfernen oder die Position eingeben'))
    liste.pop(pop)
    return
```

Comment: You did not enter a number during `input`, instead you simply pressed enter (and got back the empty string). Add code to handle the situation where a user enters invalid input (`try-except` in a loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'stop'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742432/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-stop)

Comment: not sure this would count as a dup of that @MalloyDelacroix but the solution posted there definitely works for this question.

Comment: I'd agree with Tadhg, that's why I posted an answer (didn't find a good dupe target after posting the comment). Either way, I'll keep on looking for a bit and see if I can find anything better.

Answer (score 2):

You did not enter a number during input, instead you simply pressed enter (and got back the empty string). You need to add code to handle the situation where a user enters *invalid input*, in Python, this is performed with a `try-except` where you specify the error you're expecting `ValueError` in the `except` clause:

```
def liste_pop():
    print(liste)
    while True:
        try:
            pop = int(input('remove = Enter um das letzte Element der Liste auszugeben + entfernen oder die Position eingeben'))
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Only numbers accepted")
    liste.pop(pop)
```

Of course, this has an additional issue, what if a user enters a number outside the accepted range? An `IndexError` is raised; you'll need another `try-except` for that (I'll let you handle it on your own.)